# Как пользоваться GitHub

Tags: android, github

Здравствуйте. Мне нужен PullToRefresh от ChrisBanes. Проект с GitHub с ошибками, которую я не могу исправить. Мне посказали: " Скачай гит клиент установки ссылку на репозиторий, скачай репозиторий и откатывайся на любой каммит какой-нибудь да устроит". Можете поподробнее (желательно с картинками) рассказать как это сделать?

Comment: @Andrach, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh
https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

сомневаюсь что там могут быть ошибки =), тем более что последние коммиты были 2 года назад. читай HOW TO и попробуй прикрутить еще раз